# How to list versions of the same package in Linux Mint (Debian) by command line

Tags: debian, command-line, linux-mint

In OpenSuSE via Yast you can choose the version of a package to install it.

How could I do the same in Linux Mint?

Answer (score 2):

In Debian derivatives it’s not that common to have multiple versions of a package available simultaneously (unless multiple repositories are in use), however the tools do support specifying a version to install:

```
apt install libc6=2.27-6
```

You specify the package name followed by `=` and the desired version.

To see what versions are available, use `apt policy`:

```
apt policy libc6
```

This will show all the available versions in your configured repositories (as reflected in your local copy of the package indexes, so make sure you run `apt update` to have an accurate view), and also tell you which version is currently installed (if any) and which version would be installed by default.

If you want to keep that version installed, and not upgrade to subsequent versions, you should also put a hold on the package:

```
apt-mark hold libc6
```